# Why email field in PayPal payment button does not get included in the E-mail Notification received by PayPal

Tags: email, button, paypal, payment

I have implemented a PayPal Payment Button that works fine. However i have a question about the email field. I need only email notifications from PayPal. I don't need the **PayPal IPN**. To understand me better check at my button code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input name="email" type="email" required value="">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/thanks.php" name="return"/>
<input type="hidden" value="http://www.mywebsite.com" name="cancel_return"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Name">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Product ID">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="PAY">
</form>
```

As you can see the **email field** is empty and required and the user need to complete in order to process the form.

How can i transfer the email field information in the PayPal e-mail receipt that i receive from PayPal? Is it possible?

Can you recommend any other method to access that email field information? Maybe i can assign it into the product description which appears in the receipt.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you already believe that you know the payer's PayPal email address, and want to default it into the PayPal login form that the payer will use to make a Website Payments Standard payment on PayPal's site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email address of your buyer's PayPal account will be in the email that you receive from PayPal.  However, if you have reason to believe that the email address that you need will be different than the email address on the buyer's PayPal account, then remove the following line:

```
<input name="email" type="email" required value="">
```

And replace it with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Email">
<input type="email" name="os0" value="" required>
```